# how do I restrict UIButton title text from spilling over

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

New to posting here but got many really useful bits of help already.

I am shoving some text into a UIButton title ( UIButton setTitle: forState: )
I want only the first bit of the text to be displayed (ie only amount that fits). Currently, I am getting extra text spilling over into the view.

Is there any easy way to help stop the text from overflowing  or do I have to implement my own word wrap algorithm to micromanage the amount of text I set the Title to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you set a maximum number of lines to the associated `titleLabel` ?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SDK already implemented the algorithm and there are a number of options. There is a [lineBreakMode](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/lineBreakMode) property which you can use. You can use [UILineBreakModeTailTruncation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILineBreakModeTailTruncation) as the value. However, this property is Deprecated in iOS 3.0. You need to use [titleLabel](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel) in OS 3.0

Comment: Hi Taskinoor, Not quite sure how this helps.... I can truncate the end of a line but I want lines to wrap until they get to the bottom of the button.

Comment: u can set numberOfLines of titleLabel to more than one.

Comment: Basically titleLabel is an UILabel. So you can do everything that you can do with a normal label. Hope it helps.